# Trying to find all nodes that has no "modifier" children with & at all

Tags: xpath, xslt-2.0

Xpath puzzle

```
/parameter_list/parameter[//modifier[.='&amp;']]
```

returns some results

This does not return any result

```
//parameter_list/parameter[not[//modifier[.='&amp;']]]
```

It should.
I am trying to find all parameters that has no modifier descendants with & at all
.

Comment: You need `//parameter_list/parameter[not(modifier='&amp;')]`, but I'm not sure whether `'&amp;'` wil match `&` character

Answer (score 0):

fix:

```
//parameter_list/parameter[not(.//modifier[.='&amp;'])]
```

Comment: For children it suffices to use `//parameter_list/parameter[not(modifier[.='&amp;'])]`. With `.//modifier` you are checking descendants. Also given you have used the [tag:xslt-2.0] you could also use the more verbose but closer to natural language `//parameter_list/parameter[not(some $mod in modifier satisfies $mod ='&amp;')]` or `//parameter_list/parameter[every $mod in modifier satisfies $mod !='&amp;')]`.

Comment: descendants rather sorry